# Why is my entire custom stylesheet being ignored at a certain screen width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and have both the framework CSS and a custom CSS file linked in my header. Up until I migrated from Bootstrap 2 to 3 and changed a few other things along the way (unfortunately I can't pinpoint the moment this occurred), everything was working fine between mobile and desktop. I've hardly changed my custom CSS file, besides organizing it and minor edits.

Basically, my custom CSS works fine up until the window is resized to below around 842 or 843px. I'm stumped because I haven't even used that as a media query anywhere, and I don't think Bootstrap has, either. The entire file's styles just get ignored at that size and smaller.

Here's what my header looks like (I'm using PHP):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!-- Meta -->
<title><?=$section?><? if ( $page ){ echo ": ".$page; } ?> &middot; UI Pattern Library</title>
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" name="viewport">
<meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">-->

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />

<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If it's significant at all, I'm also about to switch from CSS to LESS and just downloaded a 3rd party compiler and added my files to it. However, I am not linking the CSS file I have them compiling to, just my original one.

Comment: Yeah,,,and don't do this `maximum-scale=1.0;` it's poor UX

Comment: `<meta content="...">` attributes should be separated by a `,` not a `;`

Comment: Can you post a link to the site?

Comment: Any need for that 2nd width=device-width meta tag?

Comment: @GSaunders unfortunately the site is NDA for now so I can't push it live :(

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I DID have a loose media query in my custom stylesheet that I didn't close...